# angular directives not working with my directive

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

i created a directive called bootstrap-switch and put it as attribute to and input tag. 
now, when i am trying to add some angular directives (like: ng-show, ng-disabled) it isn't working!
the html:

```
<input ng-show="false" type="checkbox" name="my-checkbox" bootstrap-switch>
```

the js:

```
sharedSwitch.directive('bootstrapSwitch', ["regService",
    function(regService) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            require: '?ngModel',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {

                if (Number(attrs.ioStatus))
                {
                    $(element).bootstrapSwitch('state',true,true);
                }
                else
                {
                    $(element).bootstrapSwitch('state',false,true);
                }

                $(element).bootstrapSwitch('onSwitchChange',function(event,state){

                    flagNumber = Number(scope.baseFlag) + Number(scope.$index);

                    regService.fSave('F',flagNumber ,state);

                });
            }
        };
    }
]);
```

the input is showed any way.. and that because of the "bootstrap-switch" and i dont know why or how to fix it...

thank you for your help!

Comment: Not at all clear what problem is. Also there is no `attrs.ioStatus` shown on element. Create a demo that reproduces issue. Note that the plugin wraps the checkbox so you should be checking inside directive probably whether to call plugin or not

Comment: 1: check if have error in browser console 2: ngModel is required in directive and your input not have ngModel

Comment: i drop down the attrs.ioStatus state in the last second.. that isn't the probelm.. why i have to insert ng model?